# An elaboration of a second example of strict inequality in Fatou's lemma (pg.83 Royen $4^{th}$ edition).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

The example is given below:

> [image]

My questions are:

1- I can see that $g_{1} = 1$ when $x \in (1,2),$  $g_{2} = 1$ when $x \in (2,3),$  $g_{3} = 1$ when $x \in (3,4),$  $g_{4} = 1$ when $x \in (3,4)....$

then how $\{g_{n}\}$ converges pointwise to $g = 0$ on $E$?

2- why we exclude $n$ and $n +1$ from the domain of $\chi$? Actually my professor did not exclude the $n$?

could anyone explain this for me, please?

**EDIT:** for the second question I am just trying to understand how we creat examples.

Answer (score 2):

1. The sequence $g_n$ "converges *pointwise* to $g=0$" on $E$ means for each given $x\in E$, 
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)=g(x)=0\tag{1}
   $$

   For instance, $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(1)=g(1)=0$.

   Note that for any fixed real number $x$, $\{g_n(x)\}$ is a sequence of real numbers.
2. A short answer: it does not matter. It is more or less a matter of taste. 
   You could try using the definition of pointwise convergence to show that (1) remains true for $g_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$.